# Automated filling forms from a csv using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping this website :

https://login.aviva.com.sg/directinsurance/homeinsurance.htm

I want to fill all the form elements from a csv file (we will call it "profil". When I try to fill the form with a unique "profil" everything is working fine. But when I do my loop on the different profiles I have multiple problems:

- sometimes I can't "get" the full address from the postalcode (see below) and so I can't get the final quotation
- the driver is refreshing but I don't have the quote from the different people in profil. 
  Here is a type of profil that I have:

  ```
            profil = [["MRS     ","Corinne","SIMON","F","M","600     ","No, for myself and my family","72603190","2017-H1","CO      ","Ridout Road","10","91 - 124","27 - 38","099197","S4553141D","1958","5","1"],

            ["MS      ","Corinne","MOREAU","F","D","610     ","Yes, for myself","63856280","2017-H1","CO      ","Stevens","10","38 - 208","24 - 40","099198","S9186686B","1999","10","1"],

            ["MDM     ","Corinne","DUBOIS","F","W","620     ","Yes,for my family","71852991","2017-H1","CO      ","Stevens","10","38 - 208","24 - 40","099200","S2243858A","1974","2","1"]

      ]`
  ```

This is the python code that I have made so fare :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv



driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://login.aviva.com.sg/directinsurance/homeinsurance.htm")



for people in profil: 

  dropdown_salutation = 
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name("person.salutationRef"))
  dropdown_occupation = 
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name("person.occupationRef"))



  dropdown_maritalstatus = 
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name("person.maritalstat")) 
  dropdown_gender=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("person.gender"))
  dropdown_dobDay= Select(driver.find_element_by_name("dobDay"))
  dropdown_dobMonth=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("dobMonth")) 
  dropdown_dobYear=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("dobYear"))
  dropdown_declaration1=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("declaration1"))
  dropdown_declaration2=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("declaration2"))

#now we look for all the other element that we can fill (we select by id first)
  FamilyName_input = driver.find_element_by_id("surname")
  GivenName_input  = driver.find_element_by_id("givname")
  NRIC_input       = driver.find_element_by_id("nric")
  PostalCode       = driver.find_element_by_id("postalCode")
  MobileNo         = driver.find_element_by_id("textfield5")
  Email            = driver.find_element_by_id("email")


# Then we fill everything
  dropdown_salutation.select_by_value(people[0])
  GivenName_input.send_keys(people[1])
  FamilyName_input.send_keys(people[2])
  dropdown_gender.select_by_value(people[3])
  dropdown_maritalstatus.select_by_value(people[4])
  dropdown_occupation.select_by_value(people[5])
  MobileNo.send_keys(people[7])
  NRIC_input.send_keys(people[15])
  dropdown_dobYear.select_by_value("people[16]")
  dropdown_dobMonth.select_by_value(people[17])
  dropdown_dobDay.select_by_value(people[18])
  Email.send_keys("ada@hotmail.com")
  dropdown_declaration1.select_by_value("Y")
  dropdown_declaration2.select_by_value("Y")


  PostalCode.send_keys(people[14])
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# Now we can get the full address based on the postal code we provide
#here I have a first problem
  driver.find_element_by_id("btnAddress").click()

  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
  element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'immediateFamilySaf')))




  dropdown_declaration3= 
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name("policy.immediateFamilySaf"))
  dropdown_declaration3.select_by_value("N")

# Now we click on next to move forward on the second page of the form

  Next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*=checkFirstTab]")
  Next.click()


  UnitNo = 
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*=proceedNoUnitNo]")
  UnitNo.click()

  #Now we can fill the "cover needed" form 
  dropdown_plan=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("homeProd.planTypeRef"))
  dropdown_dwelling = 
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name("homeProd.dwellingTypeRef"))

  dropdown_insureadr= 
  Select(driver.find_element_by_name("homeProd.addressType"))
  dropdown_coverday=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("coverStartDay"))
  dropdown_covermonth=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("coverStartMonth"))
  dropdown_coveryear=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("coverStartYear"))
  dropdown_plan.select_by_value("HI      ")
  dropdown_dwelling.select_by_value(people[9])
  dropdown_insureadr.select_by_value("S")
  dropdown_coverday.select_by_value("1")
  dropdown_covermonth.select_by_value("4")
  dropdown_coveryear.select_by_value("2018")

# Now we can grab the next button and pass to the third tab
  SecondTab = driver.find_element_by_name("_target0")
  SecondTab.click()

#now we can grab the quote 
  ThirdTab = driver.find_element_by_name("_target1")
  ThirdTab.click()

  time.sleep(3)
  driver.save_screenshot('img' + people[2] + '.png')
  html= driver.page_source
  doc=

# We can feed that into Beautiful Soup
doc = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


rows = doc.find('table', id='table-termsofplan').find_all('td', attrs={'class': None})

premiums = []
for row in rows:

# Find the ones that don't have 'style' as an attribute
if 'style' in row.attrs:
    # Skip it! It's a header or footer row
    pass
else:
   premium={
           'type of plan': rows[1].text,
           '12 Months premium':rows[2].text,
           '24 Months premium':rows[3].text,
           '36 Months premium':rows[4].text,
           'Total Premium 12 Months':rows[10].text,
           'Total Premium 24 Months':rows[11].text,
           'Total Premium 36 Months':rows[12].text,
           'Goods and services Tax 12 Months':rows[14].text,
           'Goods and services Tax 24 Months':rows[15].text,
           'Goods and services Tax 36 Months':rows[16].text,
           'Single Payment 12 Months':rows[19].text,
           'Single Payment 24 Months':rows[20].text,
           'Single Payment 36 Months':rows[21].text,
                          }


premiums.append(premium)
driver.get("https://login.aviva.com.sg/directinsurance/homeinsurance.htm")
```

driver.close()

```
import pandas as pd

premium_df = pd.DataFrame(premiums)


premium_df.to_csv("premium.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Just after calling `time.sleep(3)` at the end of the loop, grab a screenshot by calling `driver.save_screenshot('screen' + people[1] + '.png')`. This way you'll come to know what values it is saving.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for your reply. I updated my code like below. I did what you suggested and I get the screen for the 2 profiles so I guess the problem is right after when I get the html code of page but I don't know how to resolve it. Thank you very much for your help.